# change recording video size during record

Tags: android, camera, recording

Is it possible to change the recording Video size during the recording.

The use case is to change the videosize depending on the mobile connection speed during the recording.

Comment: Any ideas? I dont find any solution.

Comment: Are you developing an application or a media framework?

Comment: Im developing a video recording stream application. So my goal is to implement a video recorder, that change the quality (Video resolution and encoding bitrate) while recording "live".

Comment: So you are going to develop your own recorder other than using the system recorder, right? You will write native code and create everything from scratch based on OpenMax interfaces?

Comment: No I use the system recorder and want to use the h.264 codec. The variability is to change the recording video size and bitrate on the fly while recording. I dont want to use other resources like OpenMax.

Comment: I am afraid that current Android release does not support such feature. Many third party achieve this goal by creating their own recorder.